# About parameters of an initial MOSFET in LTSpice

Tags: mosfet, ltspice

I'm simulating the voltage propagation of the gate circuit made up of pmos/nmos/cmos with LTSpice, and I am meeting some troubles that the plots seem to be wrong (the MOS can be abstract as a switch so that I think it shouldn't depart from the 'vi' voltage too much) and confusing. My work is to compare these gates' transfer characteristics and find out which's better.

I wonder what's the parameters of the initial MOS elements and if my circuit has problems? Thanks a lot for correcting my mistakes!

Below's my circuit and plot of **the NMOS gate circuit** ('vi' for the input and V(n001) for R1's voltage):
[image]

Comment: _”plots seem to be wrong”_ Please explain how you believe they should look compared to the simulated results.

Comment: @winny Well, I reckon it should not depart too much from the 'vi' voltage since the gate circuit can be abstract as a switch.( I'm not that sure if it's wrong)

Comment: Your cmos switch does not look correct to me. I suppose you are looking for a transmission gate? Check this link https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/what-is-a-transmission-gate-analog-switch.html#:~:text=the%20example%20device.-,Basic%20Operation,the%20input%20to%20the%20output.

Comment: @sai thanks a lot, I mistook the inverter and switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what's the parameters of the initial MOS elements

These "initial" defaults are devices that would be used in IC design, in some idealized CMOS process. These are "representative" defaults, but I doubt there are any physical realizations that match them.

You'd want to use discrete mosfets for this, so you need models of them.

I would start with perhaps the only bonded-out IC mosfets you can actually buy - CD4007, HEF4007, etc. The models for those are hard to find, so you would probably want to experiment. And look at the application notes for the 4007 - I'm sure it'll give you some starting points.

Finally, neither junction transistors nor junction FETs nor MOSFETs "are" switches. You need to *configure them* to be switches! They don't read your mind so to speak, and anyone calling them "switches" in introductory materials is doing a bit of a disservice to the reader. Because the reader assumes that switching is an inherent property, whereas it's only a consequence of configuring the device such that it works as a switch in the particular application you have.

> the plots seem to be wrong

They look roughly reasonable to me :)

> the MOS can be abstract as a switch

No. It can't read your mind that you want to use it as a switch. You have to *make it* a switch by setting things up correctly.

Just look up how transmission gates look, and you may see what problems you have :)